# Oracle OSB gather messages with same id and send them to a JMS Queue

Tags: oracle11g, middleware, weblogic11g, osb, oracle11gr1

I have to implement an adapter that does not immediately routes messages to a JMS queue, but instead waits and gathers messages with the same id, concatenates them to a list and then sends the list as a single message to the queue. Is this technically possible in the Oracle OSB?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a batch processing it is possible because you know that last message has arrived and you are ready for consolidation.

One way - Dump all the messages in to a file/db, read the file/db and do necessary transformation that is required and send to the queue.

In real time it won't be possible until you know the identifier for the last message, after that consolidation has to start.

Comment: You can also use the Unit of Order facility of 11G SOA Suite and 12C OSB to do similar things.